# xtext custom validator error marking

Tags: validation, xtext

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE demo {
   a int,
   b int, 
   PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c)
};
```

Each row is a

```
Columns
  : k=ID v=ComparatorType (is_pk?=K_PRIMARY K_KEY)?
  | is_pk?=K_PRIMARY K_KEY '(' cs+=ID (',' cs+=ID )* ')'
;
```

I invoke my error function like this

```
error('PRIMARY KEYS id need to declare in advance', 
  MyPackage.Literals.COLUMNS__CS,
  PRIMARY_KEYS_DONT_EXIST)
```

It could find the grammar error but xtext will mark error at first element of `PRIMARY KEY` row, which is `a` in my example. Is there any way to mark the error at `c` or whole `(a, b, c)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the index which should be marked as an additional argument to the error function. If you want to mark not only the c, you can of course create more than one error for each index.

Comment: great! didn't know I could do this while reading the document

Comment: Hi @Sebastian new I'm writing quickfix for this. How do I retrieve `index` in `ISemanticModification . apply` ?

Comment: Good question, it's unfortunately not part available on the Issue that shall be resolved by the semantic modification. Could you file a ticket against Xtext? Meanwhile, you may want to reconstruct the location by means of NodeModelUtils.findLeafNodeAtOffset and find the index and value starting from there